# Retrieve PFFiles from multiple PFUser objects error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

I have an array called `allMyContacts`, it stores `PFUser` objects (the current users friends). Every user has a profile image, that i want to set near their usernames in a UITableViewCell.

I could display their names, but i get an error when i try to load the images into the `PFImageView`. The error is: `'-[UIImageView setFile:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17ebaea0'` .

I think the error is in this line:`PFFile *file = [user objectForKey:@"imageFile"];`, but don't know what. Every user has an existing profile image under the `imageFile` column, therefore it can't be a nil. I suspect that the table view could be also a reason, because i'm using almost the same code in a different view, where i set the profile images and it works.

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    FriendsCell *cell = [self.tableViewTwo dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"friendsDevCell"];

    if (self.allMyContact == nil) {
        return cell;
    }
    else {
        PFUser *user = [self.allMyContact objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            PFFile *file = [user objectForKey:@"imageFile"];

            cell.profilkepView.file = file;

            [cell.profilkepView loadInBackground];

        cell.mySimpleContactUsernameLabel.text = user.username;

        return cell;

            }


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a custom file parameter in you profilIView, I don't believe you can call cell.profilkepView.file directly. You may want to try this:

cell.profilkepView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:file];

Comment: It doesn't works. I need to use the .file, because i'm using the PFImageView. I'm sure, it works well elsewhere without table view.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the Parse docs and I think you need to go through loading the URL yourself. Here's my second try:

```
PFFile *file = [user objectForKey:@"imageFile"];
NSURL *imageURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:file.url];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
cell.profilkepView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```